# How to implement a login system using token for several devises

Tags: api, rest, zend-framework, token

We are developing an API Rest services layer using Zend Rest Server framework. 
The thing is that we would like to implement the login system using tokens but we are not sure how should it work if user do login in from several devices or browsers at a time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically these could be some basic guidelines:

- Make a normal (Form) login
- Implement a token based Authentication and Authorization mechanism in paralel with your normal (Form) login
- Issue tokens on every unique login, have the tokens expire in say 10-15 minutes (or whatever)
- Don't worry about the different devices - all separate logins will have separate PHPSession Ids. But also manage the devices - one unique login == one token. So different simultaneous logins == different tokens. It is worth it to mention that this may not be the exact case for some devices and especially if you're not handling sessions (or and cookies) properly. Apple devices had some problems with this but you should do your own research.

This could be the basis. Extend and re-evaluate this approach. Also keep in mind the difference between Authentication and Authorization - this is [very well formulated here](https://serverfault.com/questions/57077/what-is-the-difference-between-authentication-and-authorization).
Also you could implement [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) as a base for the authentication system.